# Javascript - map(function) return this.value - comma on wrong side

Tags: javascript

I use this code for listing all checked values in the array:

```
   var healthSafety = $('input:checkbox[name=health_safety]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value + (' ');
   }).get();
```

but the problem is, that comma, which separates them falls in the wrong place.

I get something like:

**Tripple ladders ,Skylight ,Access to roof**

but I want something like this:

Tripple ladders, Skylight, Access to roof.

I tried to put:

```
   return this.value + (' ');
```

but it didn't helped

Is any way to fix it?

Comment: Where is the comma character even coming from?  Is it already in the value from the checkbox?  Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Can you show your HTML as well

Comment: @David I expect the comma is the result of converting an array to a string.

Comment: if you `return this.value + (' ');` an empty space will be added after the value, if you want it before, you *could* `return ' ' + this.value;` but what you really **should** do is something like: `var healthSafety = $('input:checkbox[name=health_safety]:checked').map(function() { return this.value }).get().join(', ')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're relying on implicit `join`, which puts a comma after each item, but your items (once you update them) end with a space.

Do an explicit `join` instead with the separator you want:

```
var healthSafety = $('input:checkbox[name=health_safety]:checked')
    .map(function() { return this.value; })
    .get()
    .join(", ");
```

or perhaps

```
const healthSafety = $('input:checkbox[name=health_safety]:checked')
    .get()
    .map(({value}) => value)
    .join(", ");
```

Answer (score 3):

In your question, you are viewing the default serialization of your array, which only uses a single-character `,` as a separator. You're trying to add spaces to the separation by adding them to the values.

But you don't want the values to include spaces: that will result in an extra space either at the beginning or ending of the string. Instead, you want to serialize the array with the two-character separator `,`  (comma + space). You can perform this serialization with `join`:

```
$('...').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the offending code, but somewhere you're stringifying an array, which automatically concatenates all of the elements with a comma:

```
console.log(['a', 'b', 'c']); //-> "a,b,c"
```

In your case, you're adding a space to the end of each value, so you're ending up with something like this:

```
console.log(['value1 ', 'value2 ', 'value3 ']); //-> "value1 ,value2 ,value3 "
```

What you want to do is remove the extra space as you currently have it and then call `.join(', ')` on the array - notice the extra space after the comma:

```
console.log(['value1', 'value2', 'value3'].join(', ')); //-> "value1, value2, value3"
```

You can join the array with any string:

```
console.log(['value1', 'value2', 'value3'].join('.:::.')); //-> "value1.:::.value2.:::.value3"
```