# JavaScript map(function) return this.value - finding the last element in the array

Tags: javascript, html

Following the previous query:

[Javascript - map(function) return this.value - comma on wrong side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68397287/javascript-mapfunction-return-this-value-comma-on-wrong-side)

I have one of the elements, which I would like to have distinguished.
Namely, I want the " - " element behind this object.

I found some solutions here:

[Javascript Map Array Last Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176352/javascript-map-array-last-item)

and tried to fiddle with my code, which unfortunately didn't work.

**HTML:**

```
      <fieldset id="ophealth_safety">
      <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="opladdert" name="health_safety" value="Triple ladders">
      <label class="checking" for="opladder">Triple Ladders</label>
      </div>
      <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="opgardens" name="health_safety" value="Access private gardens required">
      <label class="checking" for="opgardens">Access private gardens required</label>
      </div>
      <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="opskylight" name="health_safety" value="Skylight">
      <label class="checking" for="opskylight">Skylight</label>
      </div>
      <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="oploft" name="health_safety" value="Access Loft">
      <label class="checking" for="oploft">Access Loft</label>
      </div>
      <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="oproof" name="health_safety" value="Access to roof">
      <label class="checking" for="oproof">Access to roof</label>
      </div>
      <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="opother" name="health_safety" value="Other">
                                                <label class="checking" for="opother">Other</label>
                                                <input type="text" id="opotherdesc" name="other" pattern="[A-Za-z].{4,}" title="The text should include at least 4 letters" placeholder="Please specify">
                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
    var healthSafety = $('input:checkbox[name=health_safety]:checked').map(function() {
    const lastIndex = row.length - 1;
    row.map((rank, i) => {
        if (i === lastIndex) {
            .join(" - ")
        } else {
            return this.value;
            }).get().join(", ")
    });
```

I have currently:

**HEALTH AND SAFETY:  Access private gardens required, Access Loft, Other ceiling**

and I want something like this:

**HEALTH AND SAFETY:  Access private gardens required, Access Loft, Other - ceiling**

What is missing in my code?

Comment: Please, reformat your html code, so the code gets a better readability. Thanks.

Comment: If the callback of `.map()` does not return a value in every path or if you don't use the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is not the right tool.

Comment: Why the nested maps()? hard to understand what is happening?

Comment: `row.slice(0, -1).join(", ") + " - " + row.slice(-1)` or just a plain old `for` loop, or `.reduce()`, or ...

Comment: I have formatted the HTML code

Comment: @Andreas .map(function() { return this.value; })
    .get()
    row.slice(0, -1).join(", ") + " - " + row.slice(-1);  doesn't work. Where this row.slice should go?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get your problem right, but I will try to help.

The first problem you would like to solve is to get a comma-separated list of values of checked checkboxes, which could be something like this:

```js
const selector = 'input[name="health_safety"]:checked';
const values = Object.values(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).map(input => input.value);
```

Now that you have your list, you want to check whether "Other" (last element)  is available in the list. If yes, you want to append '-' followed by the value of the text input:

```js
let healthSafety = values.join(', ') + (
    values[values.length - 1] === 'Other' 
        ? ' - ' + document.getElementById('opotherdesc').value 
        : ''
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afe8otzn/3/

Comment: It works on JSFiddle, but how to combine it with  var healthSafety = $('input:checkbox[name=health_safety]:checked')

I tried:
var healthSafety = const selector = 'input[name="health_safety"]:checked;'
I think everythig should go within some function

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The resulting string is stored in `result`. You can instead assign it to `healthSafety` if you like :)

Comment: Could you show me how to include it in var healthSafety ?